# Firebase Functions Cannot find name 'BigUint64Array', ''BigInt', ''BigInt64Array'

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
```

Description:

Since updating to firebase-functions 3.11.0, I get following error when trying to deploy my functions with `firebase deploy --only functions`:

```
node_modules/@types/jsdom/ts3.5/index.d.ts:8:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigInt'.

8         BigInt: typeof BigInt;
                         ~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/jsdom/ts3.5/index.d.ts:9:31 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigInt64Array'.

9         BigInt64Array: typeof BigInt64Array;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/jsdom/ts3.5/index.d.ts:10:32 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 
'BigUint64Array'.

10         BigUint64Array: typeof BigUint64Array;
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 3 errors.
```

Even going back to the previous version doesn´t seem to solve the issue, so I´m not sure if the update was the trigger.

#edit 1 (full package.json)

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: do you have in `engines` in `package.json`?

Comment: After a while of thinking all `package.json` will be use full... From which version you have updated and is firebase only thing you have updated?

Comment: @vitooh I updated from `"firebase-functions": "^3.7.0"`. I also updated my question and added the full package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it. From [npm @types/jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jsdom) I went to package homepage where I found [this part](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-do-i-get-them).

It seems that you need to install additional package:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

I have replicated this issue with `firebase init` and replacing `package.json` with yours. I got the same issue than. After package install with above command my function was deployed with no errors.

One remark: you do not have `@types/jsdom` in `package.json`, which according to my understanding should be there. I have installed this package before replacing the file, to have similar situation.

Comment: Thanks, the functions now properly deployed after running `npm install --save-dev @types/node`. Weird, because I don´t remember removing anything from my package.json.Also looked through previous commits and branches and never had `@types/node` in the package.json.